# Finding Taylor Series

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hello, I'm stuck on this problem in my homework. I was hoping someone would be able to help me out?

Comment: So you tell me--how do you find the coefficients of the Taylor series for a function?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Not quite. Your series is centered at $x=0$.

Comment: I did not see that the centre was $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{1}{1 - 7x} = \dfrac{\frac{-1}{34}}{1 + \frac{7}{34} \cdot (x-5)}$. Next use: $\dfrac{1}{1+a} = 1 - a + a^2 - a^3.... +... $ with $a = \frac{7}{34}\cdot (x-5)$ and simplify.